# NodeJS - Esperar que o 'for' execute todos os 'pool.query' até o final

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, for

Estou com um pequeno problema e por mais que tenha tentado arranjar uma solução, não consigo pensar numa excelente. Por isso venho pedir a vossa ajuda!

Então é o seguinte, eu estou atualmente a desenvolver um site de apostas (de skins do jogo CSGO) e o meu problema é no NodeJS (Socket Server) devido às consultas que ele faz na database.
Em algumas funções é necessário efetuar um loop com o 'for' por todos os IDs de um Array, e cada um deles irá efetuar uma Query (Consulta na Database) e somar um valor de cada um numa variável global. Mas na maior parte das vezes ele nem chega a consultar todos e já executa o código final, eu tentei usar um 'setTimeout' mas é muito má a ideia pois nunca há certezas se haverá alguma lentidão na consulta dos dados com a database, ou até mesmo se a array é muito grande e terá que efetuar muitas consultas até poder exibir o resultado final. Por isso muitas vezes o resultado final falta sempre alguns valores.
Aqui está um exemplo do código (uma parte):

```
for(var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
            var ThisRes = result[i];

            var VS1_Value = 0.00;
            var VS2_Value = 0.00;

            var VS1_ItemsA = ThisRes.vs1_items.split(',');
            for(var i = 0; i < VS1_ItemsA.length; i++) { // REPETE AQUI BASTANTES VEZES CONFORME O TAMANHO DO ARRAY
                pool.query("SELECT * FROM gf_user_items WHERE assetid='"+VS1_ItemsA[i]+"'", function(err2,res2) {
                    if(err2) {
                        console.log(TagGF_Error+"Error Getting Item Details from DB! (AssetID:"+VS1_ItemsA[i]+")");
                        return;
                    }
                    if(res2.length > 0) {
                        var ThisVal = res2[0].price*1;
                        VS1_Value = VS1_Value*1 + ThisVal*1; // AQUI FAZ A SOMA
                    } else {
                        console.log(TagGF_Error+"Error Getting Item Details from DB! (Empty)(AssetID:"+VS1_ItemsA[i]+"|RES2_SIZE:"+res2.length+")");
                    }
                });
            }
            if(ThisRes.vs2_eid !== null && ThisRes.vs2_items !== null) {
                var VS2_ItemsA = ThisRes.vs2_items.split(',');
                for(var i = 0; i < VS2_ItemsA.length; i++) {
                    pool.query("SELECT * FROM gf_user_items WHERE assetid='"+VS2_ItemsA[i]+"'", function(err3,res3) {
                        if(err3) {
                            console.log(TagGF_Error+"Error Getting Item Details from DB! (AssetID:"+VS2_ItemsA[i]+")");
                            return;
                        }
                        if(res3.length > 0) {
                            var ThisVal = res3[0].price*1;
                            VS2_Value = VS2_Value*1 + ThisVal*1;
                        } else {
                            console.log(TagGF_Error+"Error Getting Item Details from DB! (Empty)(AssetID:"+VS2_ItemsA[i]+"|RES2_SIZE:"+res3.length+")");
                        }
                    });
                }
            }

            setTimeout(function() { // E APÓS TER EFETUADO TODAS AS SOMAS, SEGUE O RESTO...
                var TotalValue = VS1_Value*1 + VS2_Value*2;
                var GF_ThisGameData = {};
                GF_ThisGameData["game_id"] = ThisRes.id;
                GF_ThisGameData["f_side"] = ThisRes.f_team;
                GF_ThisGameData["vs1_eid"] = ThisRes.vs1_eid;
                GF_ThisGameData["vs1_items"] = ThisRes.vs1_items;
                GF_ThisGameData["vs1_value"] = VS1_Value.toFixed(2);
                GF_ThisGameData["vs2_eid"] = ThisRes.vs2_eid;
                GF_ThisGameData["vs2_items"] = ThisRes.vs2_items;
                GF_ThisGameData["vs2_value"] = VS2_Value.toFixed(2);
                GF_ThisGameData["total_value"] = TotalValue.toFixed(2);
                GF_ThisGameData["create_time"] = ThisRes.create_time;
                GF_ThisGameData["update_time"] = ThisRes.update_time;
                GF_ThisGameData["winner"] = ThisRes.winner;
                GF_NW_CoinFlipGames.push(GF_ThisGameData);
            }, 1500);
        }
        setTimeout(function() {
            console.log(TagGF+"CoinFlip Games: "+JSON.stringify(GF_NW_CoinFlipGames));
        }, 3000);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## O Problema

Em primeiro lugar, vamos falar do problema do seu código. A função *pool.query()* me parece ser **assincrona/não-bloqueante**, de forma que iterar sobre ela para conseguir esses valores não será possível, já que ela não irá disparar o callback que você passou para ela no instante que você executar *pool.query(string, callback)*.

---

OBS.: Segue abaixo uma possivel solução para seu problema, e algumas melhoras que você pode aplicar no seu código, caso a versão do seu node seja 6.x

---

## Possível Solução

Para conseguir esses valores, de forma que não prejudique o desempenho da sua aplicação podemos usar [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

Então podemos fazer isso:

```
var arrayPromise = [];

for(var i = 0; i < VS1_ItemsA.length; i++) { 
  var asyncFunc = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    pool.query("SELECT * FROM gf_user_items WHERE assetid='"+VS1_ItemsA[i]+"'", function(err2,res2) {
      if(err2) {
        // logs de erro aqui...
        reject("mensagem de erro que você quiser");
      }
      if(res2.length > 0) {
        // faz a soma aqui ...
        resolve();
      } else {
        // logs de erro aqui...
        reject("mensagem que você quiser");
      }
    });
  });

  // Insere a promise no array
  arrayAsync.push(asyncFunc);
}

// Faz o mesmo para a segunda parte do código...

// Executa todas as promises
Promise.all(arrayPromise)
  .then(function(arrResults) {
    // Aqui você já vai ter sua variavel com o valor que você desejava, 
    // então pode colocar o que estava no "setTimeout" aqui
  })
```

---

## Melhoras no código

Você pode melhorar seu codigo aplicando *ArrowFunctions*, trocar *var* por *let* e *const* e aprender bastante sobre *Promises*